# Not getting top5 values for each month using grouper and groupby in pandas

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to get top5 values for amount for each month along with the text column. I've tried **resampling** and **group by** statement

**Dataset:**

```
text       amount      date
123…        11.00   11-05-17    
123abc…     10.00   11-08-17
Xyzzy…      22.00.  12-07-17
Xyzzy…      221.00.  11-08-17
Xyzzy…      212.00.  10-08-17
Xyzzy…      242.00.  18-08-17
```

**Code:**

```
df1 = df.groupby([’text', pd.Grouper(key=‘date', freq='M')])[‘amount'].apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(5))
```

I get group of text but not arranged by month or largest values sorted in descending order.

```
df1 = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key=‘date', freq='M')])[‘amount'].apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(5))
```

THis code works fine but does not give **text** column.

Comment: can you post an output of `df.dtypes`?

Comment: @MaxU amount - **float64**, text - **object**, date - **datetime64[ns]**

Comment: please post your desired ("right") dataset

Answer (score 2):

You can using `head`  with `sort_values`

```
df1 = df.sort_values('amount',ascending=False).groupby(['text', pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='M')]).head(2)
```

Comment: This not displaying 'TEXT' column .

Comment: I want only top5 rows but I'm getting all rows

Comment: It's grouping text along with other columns and hence producing a different combination with amount and date.

Answer (score 2):

assuming that `amount` is a numeric column:

```
In [8]: df.groupby(['text', pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='M')]).apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2, 'amount'))
Out[8]:
                         text  amount       date
text    date
123abc… 2017-11-30 1  123abc…    10.0 2017-11-08
123…    2017-11-30 0     123…    11.0 2017-11-05
Xyzzy…  2017-08-31 5   Xyzzy…   242.0 2017-08-18
        2017-10-31 4   Xyzzy…   212.0 2017-10-08
        2017-11-30 3   Xyzzy…   221.0 2017-11-08
        2017-12-31 2   Xyzzy…    22.0 2017-12-07
```

Comment: I want only top5 rows but I'm getting all rows